# Why is Hibernate Cascadetype defaults to empty array

Tags: hibernate

This is a newbie question. Apologize if it is too naive

Why is CascadeType default value empty and not SAVE. If I create an object Publisher and then add an object Book to it why wouldn't I persist it to DB. I am just trying to understand the reasoning behin the default value not set as SAVE.

Thanks for helping me on this.